# on the basis of data hide and show text fields using java script

Tags: javascript, validation

{On the selection of date picker, if the selected date is less than 3 years to the current date then text1 textbox will enable else disable ... am writing validateDate() function at onchange event but am not able to write the perfect logic ...please help me out...Thanks in Advance}

````
    <script src="D:\JS\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui-1.12.1\jquery-ui.js"></script>
    <script>
    $( function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
    } );
    function ValidateDate(){ [onchange function]  
    var inputdate=document.getElementById('datepicker').value; 
    var firstDate = new Date();
             
    }
    </script>
    </head>
    <body>
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker" onchange="ValidateDate()"></p> {Validate() call to disable text1 text box}
    <p>Date: <input type="text" id="text1" disabled></p>```
````

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```js
$("input#datepicker")[0].min=(parseInt(new Date().getFullYear())-3).toString()+"-"+((new Date().getMonth()+1).toString().padStart(2, "0"))+"-"+(new Date().getDate().toString().padStart(2, "0"))
console.log($("input#datepicker")[0].min)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

Date: <input type="date" id="datepicker" min="2018-00">
```

Technically you don't need jquery at all, but since you probably have it along with other code already, I figured what the heck.

This code gets the year, gets the month and adds 1 along with parsing it to be 2 characters long, gets the date and parses it to be 2 characters long, and then puts it all together with hyphens. After that, it just sets it to the `min` of the input.